# git difftool hangs and screen becomes unresponsive

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

My global .gitconfig file has:

```
[diff]
  tool = vscode
[difftool]
  prompt = false
[difftool "vscode"]
  cmd = \"C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin\\code.cmd\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" --diff --wait
  trustExitCode = false
```

Command `git difftool` (in PowerShell) will launch the first file in Code to show changes side by side. When I close the tab, sometimes it will take a long time before the changes for the next file is shown.

Lately, it will wait forever after I have closed one file, and the command hangs on the command line shell. Pressing `Ctrl-C` will then produce gibberish on the screen and PowerShell will become unresponsive. Sometimes, pressing `Ctrl-C` many times might quit git, but sometimes the only way is to shut down PowerShell.

What have I done wrong or is this a known issue?